# Python: searching through set of objects

Tags: python, object, set

I have a set of objects `W` that have the attributes name and a score. The `__hash__()` function is based upon the name only, and the `__eq__()` function is not defined, so it is based upon the `__hash__()` function.

Now, I want to use the score of the object. Is there a quicker way to reference to an instance than the following script? Given the way a set works, there must be...

```
tmp_obj = W(name="myname", score=0)
for obj in w_set:
    if obj == tmp_obj: break
else:
    # do nothing with obj
# do something with obj.score
```

Comment: I don't understand what your included script is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `in` operator to check for set membership. This is a constant time operation in sets and dictionaries, since they are implemented as hash tables. For lists and tuples `in` is linear time.

```
obj = W("myname", 0)
if obj in w_set:
    # do something with obj
```

Comment: But I want to use the score of the object in the set, not with the score of the temporary object. *edits question*

Comment: Why do you need a temporary object?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say how you set up your object, but why not just use `if obj.score == 0`?

```
for obj in w_set:
    if obj.score == 0:
        break
```

Or perhaps your question is about avoiding the linear search?
If you have a lot of objects and you'll be doing a lot of searches by score, you need to build an index mapping scores to objects. Presumably several objects could have the same score, so we'll build a list for each score (a set would also work):

```
from collections import defaultdict

score_index = defaultdict(list)
for obj in w_set:
    score_index[obj.score].append(obj)
```

You can now loop over the list of all objects with score zero without searching:

```
for obj in score_index[0]:
    # Do something
```